# TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the validate but it gives me the error valid is not a function

```
function Submitform() {
  alert("i am here");
  if (!$("#MForm").valid()) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}
```

NB: I am using `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

Comment: I think you can not add validation js that's why it shows this type of error

Comment: @Borealis I guess you are missing jQuery library

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function Submitform() {
  alert("i am here");
  if (!$("#MForm").valid()) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

You were missing jQuery core.

Please check in browser network tab whether **jquery.validate.js** is loading or not.

Comment: I am using this <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> and the jquery.validate.js is loading

Comment: @Borealis Can you check whether **jQuery core** is loading in browser network tab & it's loading before **jQuery validate**, because **jQuery validate** has a dependency on **jQuery core**